# Install OS on a SSD then using it inside a another machine w/ different hardware?

Tags: linux

Installing an OS on a SSD then using it inside a another machine w/ different hardware? For Linux, is is a problem with drivers or other issues? Does CoreOS or Ubuntu automatically take of any differences in hardware? Is it recommended to stay away from this procedure?

Comment: The question is asking about the portability of an installed [Linux] OS between differing hardware platforms. In the same way that a Mac Boot HDD can (usually) be moved from one machine to another, and that a Windows boot HDD can (usually) not. The SSD reference is irrelevant. Generally the answer is down to whether a "complete" set of drivers are installed or not, and how consistent the hardware platform is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is generally not a good thing to do as you said it will have a problem with the drivers along other issues, but the default motherboard hardware should overide the settings at best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to clarify, what do you mean by "the default motherboard hardware should overide the settings at best"?

Comment: i.e. the on-board graphics/sound built into the motherboard. If the computer does not recognise the current hardware it defaults to using the on-board hardware on the motherboard itself.